# Interpolation is correct for grid, but wrong for random points

Tags: coordinate-transform

I am using scipy interpolation to construct a map of two coordinates to two other coordinates --- effectively one set of coordinates are 2D cartesian coordinates (called X and Y), and the other are similar to polar coordinates (radial variable r and angle coordinate t) but with no analytical expressions in term of the cartesian coordinates. The variable r labels different contours, and t is the angle around the contour.

First:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, RectBivariateSpline
from skimage import measure
```

I start with a data set containing r as a function of X, Y at specific points. X_data has nX points, Y_data has nY points and r_data is a nX by nY array.

```
X_data = np.linspace(1.0, 3.0, 1000)
Y_data = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 1000)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(X_data, Y_data)
X_centre = 2.0
Y_centre = 0.0
r_data = ((XX-X_centre)**2 + (YY-Y_centre)**2)**0.5 + 0.25*np.sin(YY)
```

Note that this is just a mockup of the original data, which has no analytical form. I build a 2D array of X and Y on a regular grid of (r, t):

```
nR, nT = 250, 250
t_array = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0*np.pi, nT)
r_array = np.linspace(0.01, 1.0, nR)
X_grid = np.zeros([ nR, nT])
Y_grid = np.zeros([ nR, nT])
```

Now I want to find contours of r in r_data, using the following function, which uses measure.find_contours from skimage to find contours, then processes that output to get the X, Y coordinates along a complete contour of r=constant. Then I calculate the angle along the contour (Contour_t).

```
def GetContour(r, r_data, X_data, Y_data, X_centre, Y_centre):    
    Contours = measure.find_contours(r_data, r) # gives X,Y indices that form contour

    Contour_X, Contour_Y = np.array([]), np.array([])
    for contour in Contours: #combine lists of partial contours for full contour
        Contour_X = np.concatenate((Contour_X, X_data[0] + contour[:,0]/len(X_data)*(X_data[-1] - X_data[0]) )) 
        Contour_Y = np.concatenate((Contour_Y, Y_data[0] + contour[:,1]/len(Y_data)*(Y_data[-1] - Y_data[0]) )) 

    # re-arrange contour so angle is taken from Y_data = 0 on right hand side of X_centre (r=0)
    PossibleInds = np.argsort(np.abs(Contour_Y)) #indices for the best candidates for the start
    j = 0
    while True:
        if Contour_X[PossibleInds[j]] >= X_centre:
            if Contour_Y[PossibleInds[j]] >= Y_centre:
                break
        j += 1
    Ind = PossibleInds[j]

    if Ind!=0: # if it's not already in the right order (by chance)
        Contour_X = np.concatenate(( Contour_X[Ind-1:], Contour_X[:Ind]))
        Contour_Y = np.concatenate(( Contour_Y[Ind-1:], Contour_Y[:Ind]))

    Contour_l = np.zeros(len(Contour_X)) # length along the contour
    Contour_l[1:] = np.sqrt(np.diff(Contour_X)**2 + np.diff(Contour_Y)**2 )
    Contour_l = np.cumsum(Contour_l)
    Contour_t = Contour_l/Contour_l[-1] * 2.0*np.pi  # angle along contour

    return Contour_X, Contour_Y, Contour_t
```

Now find each contour for every element in r_array, then plot them over the data for a sanity check:

```
for i, r in enumerate(r_array):
   X, Y, Contour_t = GetContour(r, r_data, X_data, Y_data, X_centre, Y_centre)
   fX = interp1d( Contour_t, X) # interpolate X as a function of angle along contour
   fY = interp1d( Contour_t, Y)
   X_grid[i,:] = fX(t_array)    # now save X at fixed values of t given by t_array
   Y_grid[i,:] = fY(t_array)
   plt.plot(X_grid[i,:], Y_grid[i,:])

plt.contourf(X_data, Y_data, r_data.T)
plt.show()
```

Great. I have found the contours successfully. Now I use RectBivariateSpline to construct a map of X(r,t) and Y(r,t):

```
X_map = RectBivariateSpline( r_array, t_array, X_grid )
Y_map = RectBivariateSpline( r_array, t_array, Y_grid )
```

I can check this works by plotting the maps using something like:

```
r_test = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 50)
t_test = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0*np.pi, 50)
rr, tt = np.meshgrid(r_test, t_test, indexing='ij')
plt.contourf(rr, tt, X_map(r_test, t_test))
plt.show()
plt.contourf(rr, tt, Y_map(r_test, t_test))
plt.show()
```

and it gives exactly what I would expect. However, I actually want to randomly generate points in r, t, then use the maps to get the X, Y coordinates for the randomly generated points.

```
N = 100000
r_pts = np.random.uniform(0.01, 1.0, size = N)
t_pts = np.random.uniform(0.0, 2.0*np.pi, size = N)
X_pts = X_map(r_pts, t_pts, grid=False)
Y_pts = Y_map(r_pts, t_pts, grid=False)

plt.hist2d(X_pts, Y_pts, 100)
plt.show()
```

Now all the points are clustered at the centre, not up to r=1.0, and they definitely are not uniform in angle!

QUESTION(S): I suspect I am messing up the indexing, but I have played around and can't see an obvious mistake. Can you? Why does it look fine when I plot the maps, but using the maps on randomly generated points gives the wrong result?

I have tried various interpolation methods (interp2d, RegularGridInterpolator, map_coordinates) and these have the same issue...

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems to be about debugging your code for you.

Comment: @nicoguaro the code runs, it just doesn't perform in the way I expected. I am asking whether I am misusing the interpolation method, since the bug seems to be independent of function.

Comment: A bug does not mean that the code does not work. Getting an unexpected result might be because of a bug as well.

Comment: If you provided a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) maybe people could run your code.

Comment: I suspect you may have multiple peaks, and thus discontinuous contours, also the contours have to be sorted, if `contour[i]` is continuous, smooth, and completely enclosed for by any `contour[j] for j > i` should be possible.

Comment: Could you show the plots, for the minimum working example, you can design create some data for which the coordinates will reduce to the polar coordinates, and then try to do some variation where it fails. If you find the answer in this process you can post the answer here, or delete the question.

Comment: @PartPushed rollbacked to rev2. If you sincerely wish to delete the question, please, use the delete function. However, I would consider leaving it in its current form and continuing to cooperate with the community.